# Populating and formatting JSON into a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

Thank you in advance to anyone that is able to help me on this.  I have been trying for days to make this work, and just don't know enough about this to figure it out using examples.

I have developed an Android app that places orders in a Realtime Database.  Each order has its own ID that is generated by the app.  I would like each order to display in a row when I run the code and go into the correct column based on the column header.  I have found this [example](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/72309145?hl=en) that seems to fit my need exactly (same JSON structure), but does not work when I try to repurpose.  Here is what I have:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];
    
    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
  return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}


function insertJSON(){
  
  // this puts the keys in the correct place
  var aOneName = "id";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("orders");
  var fileURL = "<-RT DB Link ->";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL,{'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; // Retrieve entry column.
  var toRows = rows[0].length;
  var toRows = toRows + 1;
  var rowsflate = flatten(rows);
  var rowstocols  = chunkArray(rowsflate, 1);
  sheet.getRange("A2:A" + toRows).setValues(rowstocols); // sets column of IDs
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(aOneName); // A1 name
  var headers = json[rows[0][2]];
  var getHeaders = [Object.keys(headers)];
  sheet.getRange(1,2,getHeaders.length,getHeaders[0].length).setValues(getHeaders); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
  content
  var content = [];
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
    var temp2 = [Object.values(json[rows[0][i]])];// Retrieve values to be split.
    Logger.log(temp2);
    content.push(flatten(temp2));
  }
  var columncount1= rows[0].length;
  var columncount2 = getHeaders[0].length;
  sheet.getRange(2,2,columncount1,columncount2).setValues(content); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
}
```

The code works to pull the JSON data and correctly puts the keys for each order in column A starting at A2.  After that however there are 2 problems when using this code:

1. The headers are overwritten and the order of them is changed (alphabetized) - this is not a deal breaker and can reorder around this if needed, but ideally when placing the values in the cells it will look at the column header (same as the value header in the JSON) and place the correct values in the cells.
   Expected:
   [What the spreadsheet should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiTHT.png)
   Actual:
   [Reordering when code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEsn9.png)
2. `Object.values` throws the error: `TypeError: Cannot find function values in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }. (line 152, file "Code").`  I have replaced this with `.keys` and attempted to use `.map` but then receive an error message below in the line  `sheet.getRange(2,2,columncount1,columncount2).setValues(content);`:  `"The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 19. (line 161, file "Code")"`

Here is the JSON

```
{
   "12":{
      "orderAddress":"address 1",
      "orderDelivered":"No",
      "orderDent":2,
      "orderDish":0,
      "orderEmail":"Not Provided",
      "orderId":"12",
      "orderLatLong":"Not Captured",
      "orderLend":1,
      "orderName":"Name 1",
      "orderPaid":"No",
      "orderPhone":"Phone 1",
      "orderSans":0,
      "orderSign":8,
      "orderText":6,
      "orderTint":0,
      "orderTotal":17,
      "orderTotalCost":200,
      "orderTrain":0,
      "orderTree":0
   },
   "13":{
      "orderAddress":"address 2",
      "orderDelivered":"No",
      "orderDent":0,
      "orderDish":1,
      "orderEmail":"Not Provided",
      "orderId":"13",
      "orderLatLong":"Not Captured",
      "orderLend":1,
      "orderName":"Name 2",
      "orderPaid":"Yes",
      "orderPhone":"Phone 2",
      "orderSans":0,
      "orderSign":0,
      "orderText":0,
      "orderTint":0,
      "orderTotal":27,
      "orderTotalCost":40,
      "orderTrain":0,
      "orderTree":0
   },
   "-MMIu9hQrxlZNs91nl2M":{
      "orderAddress":"address 3",
      "orderDelivered":"Yes",
      "orderDent":0,
      "orderDish":0,
      "orderEmail":"Not Provided",
      "orderId":"-MMIu9hQrxlZNs91nl2M",
      "orderLatLong":"Not Captured",
      "orderLend":1,
      "orderName":"Name 3",
      "orderPaid":"Yes",
      "orderPhone":"Phone 3",
      "orderSans":0,
      "orderSign":0,
      "orderText":0,
      "orderTint":0,
      "orderTotal":1,
      "orderTotalCost":12,
      "orderTrain":0,
      "orderTree":0
   }
}
```

Again, any direction on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: About `Expected: What the spreadsheet should look like`, I cannot understand about the logic for retrieving the order of header you expect. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike The goal for the header is to keep it in the order of the "Expected" picture.  When running the script, the order of the headers change to alphabetical. The overall goal is to push each JSON entry into each row under the correct heading.  Apologies if I explained it poorly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the help!  I receive the following error for code `const values = Object.entries(json).map(([k, v]) => {`: `Syntax error. (line 167, file "Code")`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying. I'm worry that you might have not enabled V8 runtime at the script editor. If it's so, please enable V8 runtime and test it again. If I misunderstood your situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue. By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, from your question, I proposed the script using the sample value of `Here is the JSON` as `json` of `var json = JSON.parse(content);`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike enabling V8 runtime solved the issue.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from `json` and put the parsed values with the order of header of `"id", "orderId", "orderName", "orderAddress", "orderPhone", "orderEmail", "orderLatLong", "orderDent", "orderLend", "orderTrain", "orderDish", "orderSans", "orderTint", "orderText", "orderSign", "orderTree", "orderTotal", "orderTotalCost", "orderPaid", "orderDelivered"`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- At JSON object, the order of keys are not guaranteed. So in your case, I think that giving the ordered header values is suitable.
- By declaring the header values as an array, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Declare the header values.
  2. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  3. Put the created array to Spreadsheet.

Whe above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; // Retrieve entry column.
var toRows = rows[0].length;
var toRows = toRows + 1;
var rowsflate = flatten(rows);
var rowstocols  = chunkArray(rowsflate, 1);
sheet.getRange("A2:A" + toRows).setValues(rowstocols); // sets column of IDs
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(aOneName); // A1 name
var headers = json[rows[0][2]];
var getHeaders = [Object.keys(headers)];
sheet.getRange(1,2,getHeaders.length,getHeaders[0].length).setValues(getHeaders); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
content
var content = [];
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
  var temp2 = [Object.values(json[rows[0][i]])];// Retrieve values to be split.
  Logger.log(temp2);
  content.push(flatten(temp2));
}
var columncount1= rows[0].length;
var columncount2 = getHeaders[0].length;
sheet.getRange(2,2,columncount1,columncount2).setValues(content); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
```

To:

```
// 1. Declare the header values.
const header = ["id", "orderId", "orderName", "orderAddress", "orderPhone", "orderEmail", "orderLatLong", "orderDent", "orderLend", "orderTrain", "orderDish", "orderSans", "orderTint", "orderText", "orderSign", "orderTree", "orderTotal", "orderTotalCost", "orderPaid", "orderDelivered"];

// 2. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
const values = Object.entries(json).map(([k, v]) => {
  v.id = k;
  return header.map(h => v[h]);
});
values.unshift(header);  // When you want to add the header, please use this.

// 3. Put the created array to Spreadsheet.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- When you use this script, please enable V8 runtime.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)